# XML export in Excel fails: Exporting the same exact file that I imported successfully

Tags: excel, xml, xsd.exe

I can import an XML file into Excel; however when I try to export that said XML file it then fails stating the below error:

> Cannot save or export XML data. The XML maps in the workbook are not exportable.

I tried updating the version of excel "from"

```
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20226) 64-bit
```

to

```
Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2307 Build 16.0.16626.20198) 64-bit
```

but the error still persists.